# Save a value of variable in a standalone application

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple string variable and I want to save the value when starting application, the application is a standalone and I don't want to use registery.
I tried to put the string as settings but it saved in a app.config file.

can I save a variable in the self application?

Comment: You can't save it in to the EXE file. You need to save it in some other file, like "app.config", text file, or a database of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is save the string in a text file like this:

```
var stringToSave = "MyString";
var filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\YourApplicationName\\data.dat";

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (filePath)) {
    sw.WriteLine (stringToSave);
}
```

What I am doing here is basically getting the directory of AppData and writes a file called `data.dat` in there. It should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: thanks for interisting